# Problemas com o SpringBoot - o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

Tags: java, spring-boot

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-13 08:05:53.688 ERROR 14840 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at com.sbd.xptotec.banco.Criar_Banco.main(Criar_Banco.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2299) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:979) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:806) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
... 21 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0

Minha classe de conexão:

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
@Profile({"dev"})
public class ConexaoMySQL {
public ConexaoMySQL() {
}

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keyfalls?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    adapter.setPrepareConnection(true);
    return adapter;
}
```

}

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name="Usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
/**
*
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
int id;
@Column(name="username")
String username;
@Column(name="senha")
String senha;
@Column(name="nome")
String nome;
@Column(name="cpf")
String CPF;
@Column(name="cep")
String CEP;
@Column(name="endereco")
String endereco;
@Column(name="telefone")
String telefone;
@Column(name="endereco_email")
String endereco_email;
@Column(name="sexo")
char sexo;

// funções

public Usuario(int id, String username, String senha, String nome, String cPF, String cEP, String endereco,
               String telefone, String endereco_email, char sexo) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.nome = nome;
    CPF = cPF;
    CEP = cEP;
    this.endereco = endereco;
    this.telefone = telefone;
    this.endereco_email = endereco_email;
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCPF() {
    return CPF;
}

public void setCPF(String cPF) {
    CPF = cPF;
}

public String getCEP() {
    return CEP;
}

public void setCEP(String cEP) {
    CEP = cEP;
}

public String getEndereço() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereço(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getEndereco_email() {
    return endereco_email;
}

public void setEndereco_email(String endereco_email) {
    this.endereco_email = endereco_email;
}

public char getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(char sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

// Função que permite ao usuario se cadastrar
public void cadastrar() {

}

//

// Função que permite ao usuario entar no sistema
public void logar() {

}
```

}

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Candidato")
public class Candidato extends Usuario {

```
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


int inscricao;

Locais_Prova locais_prova;
Salas[] salas;
Cargo cargo;
Prova[] prova;

@Column(name="data_de_inscricao")
Date data_de_inscricao;
@Column(name="data_nascimento")
Date data_nascimento;
@Column(name="renda")
double renda;
@Column(name="insento")
boolean insento;
@Column(name="nota")
double nota;

//funções

public Candidato(int id, String username, String senha, String nome, String cPF, String cEP, String endereço,
                 String telefone, String endereco_email, char sexo, Locais_Prova locais_prova, Salas[] salas, Cargo cargo,
                 Prova[] prova, int inscricao, Date data_de_inscricao, Date data_nascimento, double renda, boolean insento,
                 double nota) {
    super(id, username, senha, nome, cPF, cEP, endereço, telefone, endereco_email, sexo);
    this.locais_prova = locais_prova;
    this.salas = salas;
    this.cargo = cargo;
    this.prova = prova;
    this.inscricao = inscricao;
    this.data_de_inscricao = data_de_inscricao;
    this.data_nascimento = data_nascimento;
    this.renda = renda;
    this.insento = insento;
    this.nota = nota;
}

public Locais_Prova getLocais_prova() {
    return locais_prova;
}

public void setLocais_prova(Locais_Prova locais_prova) {
    this.locais_prova = locais_prova;
}

public Salas[] getSalas() {
    return salas;
}

public void setSalas(Salas[] salas) {
    this.salas = salas;
}

public Cargo getCargo() {
    return cargo;
}

public void setCargo(Cargo cargo) {
    this.cargo = cargo;
}

public Prova[] getProva() {
    return prova;
}

public void setProva(Prova[] prova) {
    this.prova = prova;
}

public int getInscricao() {
    return inscricao;
}

public void setInscricao(int inscricao) {
    this.inscricao = inscricao;
}

public Date getData_de_inscricao() {
    return data_de_inscricao;
}

public void setData_de_inscricao(Date data_de_inscricao) {
    this.data_de_inscricao = data_de_inscricao;
}

public Date getData_nascimento() {
    return data_nascimento;
}

public void setData_nascimento(Date data_nascimento) {
    this.data_nascimento = data_nascimento;
}

public double getRenda() {
    return renda;
}

public void setRenda(double renda) {
    this.renda = renda;
}

public boolean isInsento() {
    return insento;
}

public void setInsento(boolean insento) {
    this.insento = insento;
}

public double getNota() {
    return nota;
}

public void setNota(double nota) {
    this.nota = nota;
}
```

//Função que permite ao usuario inscrever-se no concurso
public void inscrever(int numero_inscricao) {

```
    this.inscricao = numero_inscricao;

}

//Função que permite ao usuario obter o boleto de pagamento
public void obter_boleto() {

}

//Função que permite ao usuario pedir a insenção de custo
public void pedir_insencao() {

}

//

//Função que permite ao candidato ver sua quantidade de erros e acertos
public void erros_e_acertos() {

}
```

}

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Funcionario")
public class Funcionario extends Usuario {

```
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


int matricula;

public Funcionario(int id, String username, String senha, String nome, String cPF, String cEP, String endereço,
                   String telefone, String endereco_email, char sexo, int matricula) {
    super(id, username, senha, nome, cPF, cEP, endereço, telefone, endereco_email, sexo);
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public int getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}

public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}
```

}

Eu tirei o @Id das classes que estavam herdando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente, quando erros ocorrerem assim, tente verificar o caused by descrito no log.

Vemos o seguinte no seu erro:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to class

Esse erro acontece devido a problemas de implementações de herança.

Se você puder, poste os casos de mapeamento de herança que você tem.

Temos 3 estratégias de herança de JPA:

- criar uma tabela única que armazene todas as informações da herança
- criar Tabela somente para as classes concretas de sua Herança
- criar tabela para todas as classes da herança

Não sei se é o caso. Por isso você precisa postar classes que implementam herança aqui.

Se você tiver implementado uma @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

E tiver colocado @Id na classe filha, vai gerar esse erro.

Por isso é importante analisar também as classes nas quais você está utilizando herança.

Só uma outra questão que desejo adicionar.

Seu projeto exige que você tenha o datasource sendo retornado explicitamente dessa maneira?

Porque se você utilizar alguns frameworks spring, talvez não seja necessário. Mas claro depende do projeto como um todo pra entender suas necessidades.
Veja se [spring-data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) pode te ajudar também.

Comment: Eu postei uma outra resposta pois é muito caractere para comentar.

Comment: Acho que o melhor seria editar a pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei o @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) na classe Usuario e começei a usar o application.properties inutilizado a classe de criação de conexão